Extracting Output From Strings Given Training Set
I would like to identify and extract portions of short strings that match patterns from an established data set. Not sure what the best ML/AI techniques for this problem would be, but I'm pretty sure they exist!
Example: I have a dataset that has a source string src, and the part of the string that identifies the "when" discussed in the source string, labeled as output below:
[
    {
        "src": "Party at Jim's place on the seventeenth", 
        "output": "the seventeenth"
    },
    {
        "src": "I'll call you Tuesday on Zoom to discuss options",
        "output": "Tuesday"
    },
    {
        "src": "How about never, does never work for you?",
        "ouput": "never"
    },
    {
        "src": "No parking on the 3rd Thursday of every month",
        "output": "3rd Thursday of every month"
    ...
]

I'd like to be able to train a model to find and extract the the most likely output from an arbitrary input string.
Questions: What ML/AI techniques could be brought to a problem like this? Or alternatives, maybe something simpler from NLTK or something?
Feels like supervised learning because there's a solid corpus of training data, but this doesn't reduce to specific classifications OR to a continuous numeric value... at least not that I know of!
Something like Word2Vec and NLTK stuff, NER seems to focus on individual words, but maybe it can do something fancy with ngrams?
Note: I'm not really interested in "when", this is just an example. My data set would have different types of output values.
My task is very similar to - and in the same domain as - the one outlined in this question from 8 years ago. Machine Learning Identification and Classification, based on string contents: General advice
I'm thinking there might be some more modern approaches involving AI/ML, maybe with embeddings etc., since this question was originally asked.

Without any better advice, I think I'm going to do a supervised learning approach where I run permutations of runs of words, but for training set and then also for finding matches.

You can certainly use NER to tag multiple words, if you want more advanced methods you might look into few-shot prompting with LLMs.

I played around with NER a bit 'til I realized that every piece of text I feed in will have exactly one of each of categories I'm trying to find. Unless I can force it to give me at least one best guess at each of the categories I'm looking for, then I'm sort of back to square one.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
